# How to detect if otp is autofilled in flutter or not?

Tags: flutter

In Flutter Application, I have otp screen on which there's a login button. After the otp is automatically filled, user clicks login and a loader appears and user is logged in. But what if user clicks login before the otp is filled? I want to handle this situation. What should i do in this?

Comment: Why is the user able to click the button before the fields are correctly filled? Why isn't it disabled?

Comment: Can you edit the question and [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it. Please note that Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you should be having a controller for the otp field. On button click check if the otp controller is empty or incomplete. If not then do further execution. Else sure message otp is incomplete.

```dart
onTap :(){
  if(otpController.text.length == 4)
  {
   //Process further
  }
  else{
   //Otp isn't right
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Try - catch to check if credentials are correct.

```
try {
            PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
              verificationId: verificationId,
              smsCode: codeController.text.trim(),
            );


            UserCredential userCredential = await 
          _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
            
          }on FirebaseAuthException catch (e){
            Print(e.toString());


          }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you using firebase, if otp automatically filled, that make your app authenticated. user don't need to press that button at all,your app listen to `authStateChanges()` and should update ui, and i assume your entire app is listen to auth state. if not, try to management that auth state in your app, using `streambuilder`, `changenotifier`, bloc management,etc. your choice.

if otp isn't there let say the user has 2 phone, and otp go in on another phone, then user should fill it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you should be having a controller for the otp field. On button click check if the otp controller is empty or incomplete. If not then do further execution. Else sure message otp is incomplete.

```
onTap :(){
  if(otpController.text.isNotEmpty || otpController.text != "")
  {
   //Process further
  }
  else{
   //Otp isn't right
 }
}
```